# Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

code:

```
$item_des = implode(',',$this->input->post('item_des'));
$item_cost = implode(',',$this->input->post('item_cost'));
$service_cost = implode(',',$this->input->post('service_cost'));
$total_cost = implode(',',$this->input->post('total_cost'));

$data = array(
            'item_des' => $item_des,
            'item_cost' => $item_cost,
            'service_tax' => $service_cost,
            'total_cost' => $total_cost,
            );

            print_r($data);
$query = $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
```

In this code I have a form where I am using jquery/ajax for inserting form value but when I am using implode function it raise an error message and i.e.

```
Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed
```

So, How can I fix this issue ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: this issue can be fixed but what about the bigger issue related to storing multiple values in same column as a csv string ?

Comment: Your post variable is array or not ?

Comment: [implode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp) function is use to convert array in string. Your variables may not array....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert $a to array to make sure you are always working with arrays when using implode

```
implode(',', (array) $a);
```

Where,

```
$a=$this->input->post('item_des');
```

and so on for the other cases. Just try this it will surely run !

Comment: I hope this helped :)

Comment: yeah it would be helping but I'm pretty sure CI returns array as it is, if you fetch it via `$this->input->post();`

Comment: (I) $this->input->post('item_des') <- This is a string
(II) $this->input->post() <- This is an array

In his attempt he is using the first Case where he is passing a string instead of an array to the implode function. 

Kindly give a thumbs up if you think i am right ! :)

Comment: $this->input->post(); is similar to $_POST[];
        
Now if you pass a key in $_POST it will return the string in that particular key. for example : $_POST['key1']; This will return the string present at key = 'key1'

Answer (score 0):

try printing each and every variable

```
var_dump($this->input->post('name')); //all these should be array
```

most probably these fields aren't array. Do you have hidden fields? or your html should look like this:

```
<input name="item_des[]" /> <!-- name should be an array instead of a string name, as shown here -->
<input name="item_des[]" /> <!-- there could be multiple inputs for each of the array you want to `implode` -->
```

now HTML will return you an array in post. Please [Implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) expects an array to convert it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your variables are not defined or not array.
Before working with your data, make sure they are defined as you think they are.

You can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php) to make sure your variables are defined and [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-array.php) to make sure they are array. Once you know what your variables are, you can treat them the way they are supposed to be (maybe sending error of you are expecting a proper defined array).

Casting them into array won't help you since it means the data aren't what you excepted. The rest if your code will probably have issues further.